# Expand macro to no code: "do {} while (0)" or "while (0) {}"

Tags: c, while-loop, macros, do-while

In my code I use a macro that should generate a log entry or it should not according to some compilation flag:

```c
#ifdef SOMETHING                                                                
    #define LOG(a)     printf ("%s", a)                                         
#else                                                                           
    #define LOG(a)     while (0) {}                                             
#endif
```

This code is working fine, but when I look in the Internet, I only see people using

```c
#define LOG(a)     do {} while (0)
```

instead of

```c
#define LOG(a)     while (0) {}
```

Are these two approaches equivalent? Should I prefer one over the other?

Comment: why did you try yourself and see the preprocessed output?

Comment: Remember that macros can have *no* bodies, i.e. `#define LOG(a) /* empty */` is a valid macro. Then `LOG("Some text");` would expand to `/* empty */;` which is a single (empty) statement.

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland : Perhaps because in trying it it may appear to work.  It is a problem in very specific circumstances.

Comment: @Clifford do {} while macro is also for ***`very specific circumstances`***. People do not experiment, they try to learn the "easy" way. But it does not work. I wonder: how could I learn programming with no internet and forums?

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland I see what you are saying, sometimes the answer _is_ "just try it", but equally people design flawed experiments, or misinterpret the results, or often draw general conclusions from undefined behavior.  Also the final question is "Should I prefer one over the other?"

Comment: @Clifford my point is: it is a part of the "gimme, gimme" culture. No effort. Why should I do (or learn) something if someone else can do it for me instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`do {} while (0)` and `while (0) {}` are not equivalent in all contexts, for example, in the latter case the user of the macro will naturally add a syntactically unnecessary semi-colon to the end so that:

```
if( error )
    LOG( "ERROR") ;
else
{
    ...
}
```

would expand to:

```
if( error )
    while(0){} ;
else
{
    ...
}
```

which fails by disassociating the `else` from the `if` because only the `while(0){}` is conditional.

It should also be noted that neither are syntactically equivalent to the *expression* `printf ("%s", a)` which has type `int` and a better definition is either:

```
#ifdef SOMETHING                                                                
    #define LOG(a)     do{printf ("%s", a)} while(0)
#else                                                                           
    #define LOG(a)     do{} while(0)
#endif
```

or

```
#ifdef SOMETHING                                                                
    #define LOG(a)     printf ("%s", a)                                         
#else                                                                           
    #define LOG(a)     0
#endif
```

So that `LOG()` can be used either wherever a *statement* is valid or wherever an *expression* is valid.  The *expression* version should be used in circumstances where the value of the expression might be used. The expansion of the *expression* in a stand-alone *statement* :

```
0 ;
```

is a valid no-op or null statement, but some compilers or static analysers may issue a warning for unused expression.

Common no-op idioms such as :

```
#define LOG(a)
#define LOG(a) ((void)0)
```

might also be considered but all suffer from lack of *syntactic* equivalence to the alternate expansion in the sense that one expansion is valid in all the contexts that the other is valid.

Answer (score 5):

They are different in that

```c
do {} while (0)
```

needs a semicolon at the end of the statement, while

```c
while (0) {}
```

does not.

So, when you write

```c
LOG ("Some text\n");
```

With the first one it expands to

```c
do {} while (0);
```

which is a single statement, but with the second it expands to

```c
while (0) {};
```

Which are two statements, the `while (0) {}` and the `;` (which is a valid stament).

This will matter when you combine it with an `if`. I you write something like:

```c
if (1)
    LOG ("Condition is true\n");
else
    LOG ("Condition is false\n");
```

with the `while (0) {}` approach this expands to

```c
if (1)
    while (0) {};
else
    while (0) {};
```

which is equivalent to

```c
if (1)
    while (0) {}
;
else
    while (0) {}
;
```

This doesn't compile, since there is an `else` without a corresponding `if`.

So, you should prefer the `do {} while (0)` approach for greater compatibility. Besides, it is more idiomatic.